# Nativescript-firebase-plugin: auth not working on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, firebase, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript sidekick on my Windows 10 computer to build my iOS app in my iPhone, but it seems that the nativescript-firebase-plugin does not work with Google Auth in iOS. Please, do you know why? I read some comments that suggested removing Google auth from setup but it didn't work for me.

In my Android app everything works perfectly fine.

This is my Angular authentication service:

```
    constructor(
    public router: Router
) {
    super();
    firebase.init({
        onAuthStateChanged: function (data) {
            console.log(data.loggedIn ? 'Logged in to firebase' : 'Logged out from firebase');
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                console.log('users email address: ' + (data.user.email ? data.user.email : 'N/A'));
            }
        }
    }).then((instance) => {
        console.log('[*] Firebase was successfully initialised');
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('[*] Huston we have an initialization error: ' + error);
    });
}
```

This is the error message:

> [ERROR] ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** The following build commands failed: CompileC /tmp/builds/_/6a0151efb9b3ac160998acc93164432d4b0f1ea7/6.3.3/6.3.0/tfm/platforms/ios/DerivedData/tfm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/tfm/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/A... AppAuth/Source/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService+IOS.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure) 'Build failed with error code 2'.

Comment: Are you using cloud build?

Comment: Yes I am @Manoj :)